# more help identifying material

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Ok, since my daughter has gotten into LEGO extensively lately, and I've pulled out all the bins that I got good deals on from prior years (like back in 2018/2019, I found one other (hopefully last) bin with some LEGO in it.  Could anyone help me identify any of these potential sets or parts of sets?  Thanks so much!!!

[image: random ziploc bag of minifigs and stuff]
[image: Random minifigs]
[image: Space-like type vehicles]
[image: transformer-like stuff]
[image: random vehicles]
[image: mostly unopened bags]

Answer (score 2):

I'm definitely seeing (parts of) the following sets in the photos:

- [4305: Cyborg Scout](https://brickset.com/sets/4305-1/Cyborg-Scout): [image]
- [6836: V-Wing Fighter](https://brickset.com/sets/6836-1/V-Wing-Fighter): [image]
- [6829: Radon Rover](https://brickset.com/sets/6829-1/Radon-Rover): [image]
- [6938: Scorpion Detector](https://brickset.com/sets/6938-1/Scorpion-Detector): [image]
- [8505: Amazon](https://brickset.com/sets/8505-1/Amazon): [image]
- [8504: Jet](https://brickset.com/sets/8504-1/Jet): [image]
- [6400: Go-Kart](https://brickset.com/sets/6400-1/Go-Kart): [image]
- [6791: Bandit's Wheelgun](https://brickset.com/sets/6791-1/Bandit-s-Wheelgun): [image]
- [2151: Robo Raider](https://brickset.com/sets/2151-1/Robo-Raider): [image]

Comment: Thanks!  Those Technic ones really had me stumped!

Answer (score 1):

You can do some research yourself if you want to dig around the set database over at Brickset (https://brickset.com)

Just glancing at the figs that are in the photos, most of this stuff is mid 1990s era sets. Ex: The ufo figures are from https://brickset.com/sets/theme-Space/subtheme-UFO

I'd just take a look at BS lego catalog around those years and you will probably be able to pick out the sets you have.

Answer (score 0):

I do see that the bottom one with all the pink and green, is probably from lego friends set: Looks like this set:https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/beach-house-41428
And I do see some medieval figurines so its probably from this set:
https://www.ebay.com/p/141206538
And I also see moon rovers so here: [ROVER](https://brickset.com/sets/6463-1/Lunar-Rover)

OH and is that INDIANA JONES?! : [INDI](https://brickset.com/sets/7622-1/Race-for-the-Stolen-Treasure)

yes it is
and also race carsRACECARS

And You're Welcome!

Comment: Ebay links are going to expire at some point. It is best to link to Bricklink, Brickset or Rebrickable. These resources are focused on LEGO so, most likely, will survive for much longer.

Comment: alright im editing

Comment: @Alex I have edited my post

Comment: Thanks!  I've been able to figure out that some of the moon rovers are from sets:  1737, 2151, 6818, 6829, and 6836.  And the sealed bags are from set 41119.